# django - how can I get a list of all foreignkeys related to a model?

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class DataSource(VoteModel, models.Model):
​
    dataset_request = models.ForeignKey(
        'DatasetRequest', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='datasource_files/')
    file_size = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
​
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Untitled")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
​
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
​
    is_csv_or_tsv = models.BooleanField(null=True)
​
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="datasource_thumbnails/", blank=True, null=True)
​
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
​
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
​
​
class DatasetRequest(VoteModel, models.Model):
    reward = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)  # if 0, 1 medal
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="datasetrequest_thumbnails/", blank=True, null=True)
​
    best_dataset_entry = models.ForeignKey(
        DatasetEntry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
​
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
​
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
​
    qa_testers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='qas')
```

With the following setup, how can I get all DatasetRequests for a given DataSource? dataset_request (DatasetRequest) is a foreignkey in DataSource. There is no many-to-many in DatasetRequest, though there are data sources for every DatasetRequest. Do I need a many-to-many for either?

Comment: did you mean get all `DataSource` objects for a given `DatasetRequest` object?

Comment: No. I want to get all the datasetrequests that use a datasource.

Comment: The foreign key field is on the `DataSource`, so there will only be one `DatasetRequest` for any `DataSource` and it's just a field on the `DataSource`. Maybe you can move the fk field to point the other way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accessor for the backwards relationship of your model.

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects):

> Django also creates API accessors for the “other” side of the
>   relationship – the link from the related model to the model that
>   defines the relationship. For example, a Blog object b has access to a
>   list of all related Entry objects via the entry_set attribute:
>   b.entry_set.all().

This uses the `related_name` field specified in the `ForeignKey` field, but is set to the model name by default.

In your example, you can do:

```
data_source = DataSource.objects.get(pk=1) # or whatever
data_requests = data_source.datarequest_set.all()
```

Now `data_requests` will be a `QuerySet` of all `DataRequest` objects that have a foreign key pointing to the `data_source`.

Comment: I'm getting "AttributeError: 'DataSource' object has no attribute 'dataset_request_set'" as well as "AttributeError: 'DataSource' object has no attribute 'datasetrequest_set'"

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr Currently this won't work, but it seemed like you need to change the direction of your foreign keys before doing this. You can currently do something like `data_request.datasource_set.all()` but you said that isn't what you're after here